# WIX: Files not copied over on new installs

Tags: wix

So, I have a WIX project which is to install either fresh installations or over previous installations of a product.  This product, if it was already installed, has several files inside of 3 different folders which need to be preserved.  This project also needs to copy the contents of those 3 different folders into another set of folders (same content in two different locations).  In order to accomplish this I have set up my project to first attempt to write into the original folders if the files don't already exist, then copy the contents of those folders.  On an upgrade where those files already exist this works fine.  On a fresh install the second set of folders do not get created, but all the files do.

My assumption, and I may be incorrect, is that the msi is attempting to copy the folders over before they have even been created.  This would cause folders to not exist in the area they were supposed to be copied to as there would be nothing to copy from.  Is there a way I can ensure the files have been generated before trying to copy them?  Is there a better way of going about this that I'm not seeing?

EDIT:

I'm going to try to clear this up a little.  What I'm trying to do is the following (pseudo):

1) See if an option file (hi.opt) exists in c:\options, if not create it.
2) Copy that file to c:\options\opt2015.

I'm doing this 3 times for 3 different folders.  I am creating the initial files with Wix in the c:\options folder using the NeverOverwrite parameter.  This part works great; the files are created without issue and none are overwritten if they already exist.  Where the problem lies is step two where I'm using the CopyFile Wix command.  This will only copy some of the files from the c:\options folder to the c:\options\opt2015 folder.  Depending on the initial setup of the system (if the files at c:\options exist or not) some files will copy over and others won't.  It's not random, the results are repeatable every time, but there seems to be no reason why some files copy and others don't depending on the initial setup of the system.

I hope this makes sense and is a little more clear, though I think it makes things worse!  It is strange behavior because to me it looks like everything should just work, but it doesn't (isn't that every bug though).

Edit2:

After more work and creating a vb script which runs perfectly outside of WIX my team and I have determined that the files just are not being seen by WIX during the installation even though they do exist.  We haven't found any permissions issues and the installation is running as admin on an admin account.  Doing the copy via a VBS or through the Wix CopyFile command results in, well the same results; files that already exist on the system are not being copied.  Any more ideas?  Should we find a solution I'll be sure to post it because this is just getting weird.

Comment: I've now discovered it isn't working sometimes if the files exist.  I'm going to try using a custom action.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your installer design should work as long as you're attempting to copy the files after the InstallFiles action runs. You should be copying the files from the first set of folders to the second set of folders by doing one of the following:

- Running a deferred custom action that executes after InstallFiles
- Using the MoveFiles action

Comment: I've been using the following:        <CopyFile SourceDirectory="SCRIPTSFOLDER" Id="SCRIPTFILES61" SourceName="*" DestinationDirectory="SCRIPTSFOLDER61"/>

Comment: When you look at your finished MSI's InstallExecuteSequence table, what's the order of the following actions: RemoveExistingProducts, InstallFiles, MoveFiles?

Comment: Remove Existing Products is 1401, InstallFiles is 4000, MoveFiles is 3800

Comment: A fresh install will work if you schedule MoveFiles after the InstallFiles action. Right now, the MoveFiles action is attempting to make copies of files/directories that haven't been installed yet by InstallFiles.

Comment: Using InstallShield I changed the order around but to no avail.  It seems that the MSI is just doing whatever it wants when it comes to order.  I actually found another example of this where both of my custom commands, which by order are run at the end of the installation, are being run before the base folder is even created which causes the installation to error out.  This MSI stuff is a madhouse apparently.

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment, but may not be an answer either....

There isn't really such a thing as "over previous installations of a product", especially if you end up with multiple instances in Programs/Features, and files that may or may not have the same component ids replacing each other - that's going to be a mess. If you need to upgrade the installed product, use a major upgrade, that seems to be where you're going with this. If you are already writing custom actions to do some of this "first attempt to write into the original folders" then I've no idea what's going on or where you doing this in the install. In general, if you need those files in the new install then add them to the new major upgrade MSI. If you need to copy the older existing files from the older product, then do a major upgrade with afterInstallExecute and write custom action code to copy them before the InstallFiles action. Or the CopyFile WiX element could do it, see the part about the element under a component with no fileid.

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/copyfile.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, as sometimes happens, the error was entirely elsewhere.  It turns out that an uninstaller for another program which was in the chain of programs which are installed at the same time was destroying the folder.  Unfortunately this is what happens when a product isn't touched for 10 years.  Thank you for your contributions, they were very helpful.  Even though I was going down the wrong path the whole time I still made use of them in my tests and am more adamant about checking the installation order.